# Movie about a girl with photographic memory

Tags: identify-this-movie

The plot is something like this, this girl was in College and she gets bullied because she's crazy smart.

One scene I remember is there's something in her dorm room, like an experiment,  with the use of a box and they threw it in the garbage then she was like crazy looking for it.

Another scene was a woman in the horse farm asking something about a horse and she answered everything she can remember (the photographic memory part).

She was about to be expelled but a professor noticed her talent and persuaded the principal that she's a genius and should not be expelled. Then the professor let the girl create an experiment like an OPTICAL ILLUSION where two figures enter the same box. The left side is bigger (it reaches the top) while the right side figure is so small. (Get it? Like, they're at the same box yet they're not the same size.)

Please help me. It's been 7 years since I've watched it. Thank you!

P.S.: The girl is really weird yet she has photographic memory.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [Temple Grandin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1278469/combined) with Claire Danes, but it's from 2010.

> Biopic of Temple Grandin, an autistic woman who overcame the limitations imposed on her by her condition to become a Ph.D. and expert in the field of animal husbandry. She developed an interest in cattle early in life while spending time at her Aunt and Uncle's ranch.

[Grandin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Grandin) is a savant with photographic memory. IIRC she has a special relationship with horses there, and here's the scene where she puts together that optical illusion (aka ["Ames Room"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ames_room)) project:

Answer (score 1):

I am 11 years old, and I don't know any movies, but I know this show called Ant Farm, and Olive has eidetic memory. She isn't the main character, but she is a very big part of it, and the actress is really good at reciting her lines and acting. I love Ant Farm!

Comment: Hello @Emma. Thank you for sharing. I hope you stick around and help the rest of us some more.